# Start exe after msi install but using current user privileges

Tags: security, installation, windows-installer, exe

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to build an MSI install package.  Within the install I have numerous custom actions.  Within the OnAfterInstall custom action I attempt to start an exe which is deployed by the install.  The exe starts ok, but runs within a security context of NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (i.e. under the elevated privileges granted to the Windows Installer process).  I actually need the exe to run in the security context of the currently logged-on user who started the install in the first place.  Does anyone know how to start the exe so it runs in this 'reduced' context.  I really want to avoid having to ask the user for their login credentials if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Remote Desktop Services API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383464%28v=VS.85%29.aspx . It is available starting from WinXP.

This API allows you to run your application in context of any logged in user account. You need to be running as a SYSTEM to be able to use it. And you are.
For instance you may enumerate sessions using WTSEnumerateSessions, then take user token by WTSQueryUserToken and run application using this token.